# Failing to parse numbers from stringstream and output them correctly C++

Tags: c++, string, parsing, int, stringstream

```
#include <iostream>        
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
string a = " test 1234 test 5678";
stringstream strstr(a);
string test;
vector<int>numvec;
int num;
while(strstr>>num || !strstr.eof()){
    if(strstr.fail()){
        strstr.clear();
        string kpz;
        strstr>>kpz;

    }
    numvec.push_back(num);
}
for(int i = 0;numvec.size();++i){
    cout<<numvec[i]<<'\t';
}
}
```

In this program , i'm trying to parse only the values " 1234" and " 5678" from a stringstream which has string words in it and output those values. I put the values inside an Integer vector , later i'm outputting those values from the vector , however , the output is that in the first few lines , it shows me the values , but then , I get alot of zero , I never saw such error and it looks very interesting , so my questions are: Why I don't get the values " 1234" and " 5678" outputted as wanted? ( which is for the program to show only those values and not the huge array of zeros caused by the error ) and why's this error happening?

For the program:  http://ideone.com/zn5j08

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: The condition in the `for` loop is always true as long as `numvec` is not empty. You most likely meant `i < numvec.size()`

Comment: Thanks , did not notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your loop does not have a `continue` after detecting a failure state, meaning that the value of `num` gets pushed into `numvec` even after a failure.

Here is how you can fix this:

```
while(strstr>>num || !strstr.eof()) {
    if(strstr.fail()){
        strstr.clear();
        string kpz;
        strstr>>kpz;
        continue; // <<== Add this
    }
    numvec.push_back(num);
}
```

Now the value gets pushed into `numvec` only when `strstr` is not in a failed state, fixing your problem.

[Fixed demo.](http://ideone.com/acJDz6)

Comment: Thank you , helped.  But Is it safe to use  ' continue ' ?

Comment: @zLeon Yes, this is absolutely safe, because each iteration of the loop makes some progress reading through the stream. This means that you wouldn't get into an infinite loop, which is the chief danger of using `continue`.